# Use \titleformat inside \begin{document}

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I would like to adjust section headings at some point in the document. However, `\titleformat` can only be used in preamble, something like the following fails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\titleformat{name=\section}[display]
  {\huge} % format
  {} % label
  {10pt} %sep
  {} %before

\section{test}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to adjust `\titleformat` in the middle of a document?

**Edit:**

```
\begin{document}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\huge} % format
  {} % label
  {10pt} %sep
  {} %before

\section{test}
\end{document}
```

works, but then how do I use `page=even` in the `\titleformat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My edit of the question already says that I can use `\titleformat{\section}[display]` instead of `\titleformat{name=\section}[display]` outside of the preamble. I still had an issue with `page=odd` and `page=even`, which can only be set with the `\titleformat{name=\section}[display]` format.

I've circumvented the problem with:

```
\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\secstyle} % format
  {} % label
  {10pt} %sep
  {\vspace{-15mm}%
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}%
  {\fancytab{\chaphead}{\arabic{chapter}}}%
  {}%
\filcenter\textls[-35]} %before
```

to apply only on odd pages.